# Can I remove upstart-* from startup

Tags: startup, upstart

When I startup my computer I have 80+ processes running - just under my name.

Of these, I have 4 that match the regex upstart-*:

```
upstart-dbus-bridge
upstart-dbus-bridge
upstart-file-bridge
upstart-event-bridge
```

is it safe to kill these? And how can I stop it from starting up automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the **upstart** is a init system as **systemd** and is very important to the system initialization.

See more:

[Upstart - official webpage](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

[Talk:Comparison of init systems - Size and complexity](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Talk:Comparison_of_init_systems#Size_and_complexity)